# Initialization order for nonstatic/static/global/subclass members

Tags: c++

I deliberately create the following code to let me easily present the question.

Question> What is the initialization order of all variables?

```
#include <iostream>

int iGlobal = 10;

class A {
public:
    A(int _a) : m_a_a(_a) {}

private:
    int m_a_a;
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    B() : m_b_b(40), A(20), m_b_a(30) {}

private:
    static int m_b_static_a;
    int m_b_a;
    int m_b_b;
    int m_b_c; // this variable is NOT initialized in the B::B() initialization list
    static int m_b_static_b;
};

int B::m_b_static_a = 11;
int B::m_b_static_b = 12;

int main(void)
{
   B b;
   return 0;
}
```

First, I list all variables as follows:

```
iGlobal, m_a_a, m_b_static_a, m_b_a, m_b_b, m_b_c, m_b_static_b
```

Here is what I think I am right.

```
m_a_a < m_b_a < m_b_b < m_b_c (i.e. X < Y iff X is initialized early than Y)

m_b_static_a < m_b_static_b
```

Rule1> C++ guarantees that variables in compilation unit (.cpp file) are initialised in order of declaration.

Rule2> The order listed in the initialized list doesn't control the order of initialization.

I have problems to order among the global variable, static variable and non-static variable.

Comment: `main` returns an `int`.  Anything else is non-Standard and not C++.  I point this out because this looks like a test you're taking and, if it is, I'd beware that the tester is an idiot.

Comment: m_b_c is not initilized at all. statics are initialized before control gets to `main`.

Comment: @John, I have correct the return value of main and this is not test.

Comment: @Roman, m_b_c is indeed initialized with somehow an arbitrary integer.

Comment: @q0987 well, that means it's not initialized. Just some garbage in there that happened to be at this particular place in the memory.

Comment: @RomanB, which one goes first global or static?

Comment: @q0987: statics in a class are basically globals.  statics in a function are initialized the first time the code is executed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Within a compilation unit, globals are initialised in the same order they're declared. However, the order is unspecified across different compilation units (see [What's the "static initialization order fiasco"?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.14)).

**Class initialisation order**:

1. Members of base classes (when inheritance is present)
2. Members of the current class
3. Constructor

Members initialisation respects the declaration order, regardless the order used in the initilisation list.

Having `class C : public A, public B`, initialiases `A`, then `B`, then `C`. And their destruction occurs in the inverse order.

**NOTE**: Virtual base classes do not respect the order mentioned above.

Quoting §12.6.2/5 from the C++03 Standard:

> Initialization shall proceed in the following order:
>
> — First, and only for the constructor of the most derived class as
>   described below, virtual base classes shall be initialized in the
>   order they appear on a depth-first left-to-right traversal of the
>   directed acyclic graph of base classes, where “left-to-right” is the
>   order of appearance of the base class names in the derived class
>   base-specifier-list.
>
> — Then, direct base classes shall be initialized in declaration order
>   as they appear in the base-specifier-list (regardless of the order of
>   the mem-initializers).
>
> — Then, nonstatic data members shall be initialized in the order they
>   were declared in the class definition (again regardless of the order
>   of the mem-initializers).
>
> — Finally, the body of the constructor is executed.

Concluding, the order will be:

```
iGlobal (global)
B::m_b_static_a (static)
B::m_b_static_b (static)
A::m_a_a (base class member)
B::m_b_a (class member)
B::m_b_b (class member)
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. In fact, I have seen both standard 12.6.2/5 and static initialization order fiasco before I posted my question here. I feel confused about the order between global, static, and nostatic rather than the order in each category.

Answer (score 2):

No, all the "globals" will be initialized before `main`:

`iGlobal, m_b_static_a, m_b_static_b, m_a_a, m_b_a, m_b_b`, and `m_b_c` is never initialized.

Comment: _Technically_ `m_b_c` is "default-initailized", but for `int` that's defined as "no initialization".  It's a weird part of the wording.  Is that initialized or not?

Answer (score 0):

The canonical initialization order is:

1. Base classes left-to-right
2. Nonstatic data members top-to-bottom
3. The body of the constructor

Here is the initialization order that I observed in VC++ 2005:

1. Global data (`iGlobal` == 10 before entering `main()`)
2. **Static** data members (`B::m_b_static_a` == 11, `B::m_b_static_b` == 12 )
3. Base classes (`A::m_a_a` == 20)
4. Nonstatic data members **in the initialization list** (`B::m_b_a` == 30, `B::m_b_b` == 40)

`B::m_b_c` remains *uninitialized* (set to `0xcccccccc`) after returning from B's constructor.